# Параметры по умолчанию в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!  У меня возникла такая проблемка. Допустим у меня есть функция MS SQL которая принимает несколько параметров. Возвращает функция результат такого запроса

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
        FirstColumn = @firstParameter
    AND SecondColumn = @secondParameter
```

дело в том что параметр функции @secondParameter может отсутствовать (ну точнее не остутствовать а быть например равным NULL)  поэтому мне бы хотелось что то такое:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
        FirstColumn = @firstParameter
    if(@secondParameter IS NOT NULL)
        <добавить условие с @secondParameter>
    else <ничего не добавлять>
```

Есть ли у кого-то идеи как такое сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
        FirstColumn = @firstParameter
        AND (SecondColumn = @secondParameter OR @secondParameter IS NULL)
```